# How to combine each n elements of array into one element

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an int array a[intPART+1] of elements of 0 and 1. 
I want to reduce the size of this array to b[rightSIZE+1], by union each n elements of the array, where

```
int rightSIZE=    -1              if (intPART+1)/n=0
                  intPART         if n=1
                   0              if (intPART+1)/n=1
                 (intPART+1)/n    if (intPART+1)modn=0
                 (intPART+1)/n-1  if (intPART+1)modn!=0
```

( I wrote these conditions for rightSIZE, I think they should work for any 
  (intPART+1) and n )

```
n can be any number that we want

For example, if we have k = intPART+1 = 8 and if array a=[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0]
     for n=1 we'll have b=[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0]
     for n=2 we'll have b=[1,11,11,01,00]
     for n=3 we'll have b=[111,110,100]
     for n=4 we'll have b=[1,1111,0100]
   for n=200 we'll have b=[111110100] and so on
```

Unfortunately, I don’t really imagine how this task can be done and this task is part of my other task, so I am attaching the last part of my code to which I want to add this solution (which is a problem for me now). Hope you can help me

I am writing in C ++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>       /* log2(dec) and fmod()*/ 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int dec=500;//let be
//Decimal to binary
int intPART = log2(dec);
cout << "Int part of log2 (" << dec << ") is " << intPART << endl;
int dec1 = dec;
int *a=new int[intPART+1];
for (int i = 0; i<=intPART; i++)
{
    a[i] = dec1 % 2;
    dec1 = dec1 / 2;
}
cout <<dec<<" in a binary system: ";
for (int i = intPART; i >= 0; i--)
{
    cout << a[i];
}
    int n=2^16;//let be
    int rightSIZE;
    if ((intPART+1)/n==0)       rightSIZE=-1;
    if (n==1)                   rightSIZE=intPART;
    if ((intPART+1)/n==1)       rightSIZE=0;
    if (fmod((intPART+1),n)==0) rightSIZE=(intPART+1)/n;
    if (fmod((intPART+1),n)!=0) rightSIZE=(intPART+1)/n-1;
    int *b=new int[rightSIZE+1];
    //what to do next? I don't know:(

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why don't you just iterate over all elements of `a` and use the of cascade? Are `intPART` and `rightSIZE` the sizes or the indices?

Comment: Concerning `int n=2^16;` This is literally "int n initialized with 2 EXOR 16". `^` denotes the bitwise XOR operation. If you want 2 to the power of 16, this can be written as `itn n = 1 << 16;`. `<<` is bitwise left shift (for integral values).

Comment: Applying floating point operations (like `fmod()`) to integral values make my "teeth hurt". ;-) There is a nice Modulo operator for integral values built-in into language: [`%`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Multiplicative_operators) - no need for any extra lib.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for your comments, I didn't know that 2 ^ 16 can be represented as n = 1 << 16 and now I know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want something like that:

```
template <std::size_t K, std::size_t N>
std::array<int, (N + K - 1) / K>
combine(const std::array<int, N>& a)
{
    std::array<int, (N + K - 1) / K> res{};

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        res[(N + K - 1) / K - 1 - i / K] += a[N - 1 - i] * pow(10, i % K);
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/f1zCmt)